# auto-accept SSL certificates in chatzilla

Tags: ssl, irc, chatzilla

I use Chatzilla to chat on IRC. When I connect to an SSL port, I'll often get the message that I need to add an exception because the security certificate is invalid. In fact, this is the rule rather than the exception.

Servers like geekshed, rizon, etc... servers everyone uses. I feel they are perfectly safe, and I'd very much like to set things up so I don't have to accept a certificate each time I connect or my connection drops for a few seconds and a reconnect happens.

Often, I'll have to request a certificate multiple times before the connection finally continues. If this was just accepted automatically it would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel they are perfectly safe

So what if they are? SSL certificate verification is *not* about whether you trust Rizon's servers. It's about knowing that you are indeed connecting to *Rizon's* servers and not to a fake server in some cracker's lair. That's why verification failure messages are so scary) - they signal that something ungood may be happening with your connection.

[image]

If you are sure a certificate is valid, add a permanent exception for every server, and you will be bothered less and less often.

---

There's [Perspectives](http://www.networknotary.org/firefox.html) but it will probably not work on ChatZilla.

Comment: I've been permanently storing exceptions for over a year now. They just keep coming every single time I connect.

Comment: @WebDevHobo: File a ChatZilla bug? (I just tested CZ 0.9.86.1 on Firefox 4.0, and it stores the exceptions just fine.)

Comment: sorry for late reply. Anyway, are you using the chatzilla firefox addon for this? I installed Chatzilla as a seperate app running on XULRunner. http://chatzilla.rdmsoft.com/xulrunner/